# generate "category-intervals" from categories

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, categorical-data

I want to generate "category intervals" from categories.
for example, suppose I have the following :

```
>>> df['start'].describe()
count    259431.000000
mean         10.435858
std           5.504730
min           0.000000
25%           6.000000
50%          11.000000
75%          15.000000
max          20.000000
Name: start, dtype: float64
```

and unique value of my column are:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20], dtype=int8)
```

but I want to use the following list of intervals:

```
>>> intervals
[[0, 2.2222222222222223],
 [2.2222222222222223, 4.4444444444444446],
 [4.4444444444444446, 6.666666666666667],
 [6.666666666666667, 8.8888888888888893],
 [8.8888888888888893, 11.111111111111111],
 [11.111111111111111, 13.333333333333332],
 [13.333333333333332, 15.555555555555554],
 [15.555555555555554, 17.777777777777775],
 [17.777777777777775, 20]]
```

to change my column 'start' into values `x` where `x` represents the index of the interval that contains `df['start']` (so `x` in my case will vary from 0 to 8)

is there a more or less simple way to do it using pandas/numpy?

In advance, thanks a lot for the help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.digitize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(start=np.random.random_integers(0, 20, 10000)))

# the left-hand edges of each "interval"
intervals = np.linspace(0, 20, 9, endpoint=False)
print(intervals)
# [  0.           2.22222222   4.44444444   6.66666667   8.88888889
#   11.11111111  13.33333333  15.55555556  17.77777778]    

df['start_idx'] = np.digitize(df['start'], intervals) - 1

print(df.head())
#    start  start_idx
# 0      8          3
# 1     16          7
# 2      0          0
# 3      7          3
# 4      0          0
```

Comment: this is eactly what I was looking for, thank you @ali_m